# How to figure out if a DataGrid Row Has been Changed in MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, wpfdatagrid

I want to Bind the WpfDatagrid Rows to a boolean Property in a ViewModel,that shows if Row Has been changed.in the fact I have a datagrid that bind to a class in the model, and have a property IsRowChanged in the ViewModel,and don't know how to bind datagrid to IsRowChanged ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Produts}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="True" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsRowChanged}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

If you use entity framework you can directly extend your entity partial class with this line

```
public bool IsRowChanged { get { return myEntity.EntityState == EntityState.Modified; } }
```